# Connection with mysql on remote server via UNIX socket

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a mysql database on remote server via UNIX sockets, and I have node.js deployed in the same server, on different directory. I try connected node.js with database, but I have problem.

My code for connection:

```
const database = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1', // is host for mysql database on remote server
    port: 3306,
    user: 'fake_user',
    password: 'fakse_pass',
    database: 'fake_db'
});
database.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('Database is connected ...');
    } else {
        console.log('Error connecting database ...');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Here, I put a fake credentials for user, password and database. The credentials I use are valid. I am logged in on phpMyAdmin on remote server.

Database server info: [image: view info]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "socket-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.0"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mysql/xdevapi": "8.0.19",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

locally:
node version: 12.16.0
npm version: 6.13.4

remote server:
node version: 12.16.1
npm version: 6.13.4

When I run locally

return error: [image: view error]

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: When run server.js on server, return me this: **Error: Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server at Packet.asError**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like with `phpMyAdmin` you are connected via UNIX socket whereas with the `mysql` Node.js module you are trying connecting via TCP host/port. Maybe that is the issue. If that is the case, you either need to bind the MySQL server to the 3306 port in your host or, alternatively, you can use the socket path when creating the pool.

```
const database = mysql.createPool({
  socketPath: '/path/to/your/unix/socket/file.sock'
  user: 'fake_user',
  database: 'fake_db'
})
```

I've noticed you are also somehow "using" the X DevAPI connector - `@mysql/xdevapi`. Just to be clear, it won't work with your setup because it is based on the X Protocol, which AFAIK is not supported by MariaDB.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js